# Microsoft Click Once An error occurred while signing: Key not valid for use in specified state

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm trying to publish the new deployment of my application to a shared location. 
and I get this error "**An error occurred while signing: Key not valid for use in specified state.**"

1. Note This is the first time doing so since moving to a new domain.
2. The shared location is in the old domain and at first I thought it was because it couldn't access the information necessary in the old share location because I didn't apply my credentials to access the old share, which could be a reason the key information could be mismatched.

after logging on with my credentials it didn't help.

Comment: Remove and add the certificate file or try generating a new temporary certificate.

Comment: That worked removing the old one and making a new one removed the old domain credentials and updated it with the current credentials.

Thank you.

If anyone wants to know where you can do this, it's in the signing tab that shows up under the project's properties.

Comment: I had this happen recently with a 3rd party app Cerebrata "Azure Explorer" after joining a domain and migrating my user profile. Since not my app, how can I delete the old certificate as I'm not sure which one it even is. Uninstalling/reinstalled did not help. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to an old question because I just had this problem after a domain change and already had a valid signing certificate working on the project. Had to re-import it and it worked after that.

Comment: I recently got the same error after transitioning to VS 2022 from VS 2019 and changing to .NET 4.8. Could be a coincidence. After deleting and re-importing the used cer-file I got presented with the error `error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: Only certificates using RSA encryption are valid for signing ClickOnce manifests.`

Comment: stumbled across this again. Here is an answer that resolves the second error that I got after a re-import: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71062341/build-of-word-add-in-error-msb3482-an-error-occurred-while-signing-only-certi
In short: re-import the private key file (usually .pfx) and not the .cer file which only holds the public key.