# Build of Word-Add-In: error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: Only certificates using RSA encryption are valid for signing ClickOnce manifests

Tags: ms-word, certificate, x509certificate, add-in, office-addins

When upgrading our solution from VS 2019 to VS 2022 and to .NET 4.8 on one of our machines the signing of a Word Add-In does not work any more. The machine was not in use for half a year so it could also be some other update stuff or so.

The csproj file has now `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

First I got another error that I could overcome which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942244/microsoft-click-once-an-error-occurred-while-signing-key-not-valid-for-use-in-s/68096069#comment125610696_68096069)

Then I got the error `error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: Only certificates using RSA encryption are valid for signing ClickOnce manifests.`

By googling I found that the error (following some translation files and the error message identifier SecurityUtil.OnlyRSACertsAreAllowed) probably comes from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/main/src/Tasks/ManifestUtil/SecurityUtil.cs) in line 675
But I don't know what to make of it. EDIT: This certificate also works on other machines so there has to be some environmental issue other than the certificate content.
The used certificate has not changed and looks normal to me.

Considering the comment of Crypt32 I can say that this is a self owned Root CA that is only for development purposes. The Add-In gets re-signed later on with a better certificate. The algorithm state

Anyhow the reason for the icon of the dialog showing a red X is probably because this Root CA is not fully trusted (see last screenshot). Of course I should not enable full trust with such a certificate. On the other machines this certificates is also not trusted so this should not be the problem here.

I also saw that the private key for the certificate was not imported into my certificate store. I then also imported the private key but there is still the same error during build.
The public key says RSA 1024 bit if that is what you ment
Crypt32. Maybe the number of bits is too low?

[image: Used certificate]

EDIT:

[image: Used certificate 2]

[image: Used certificate 3]

Comment: what is the public key algorithm in the certificate? Scroll down this dialog for a bit. In addition, the cert icon suggests that there other issues with certificate.

Comment: thanks @Crypt32 for pointing me into the right direction to check for differences in the imported certificate on the different machines!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: I had only imported the public key parts of the certificates into the certificate store and thus could of course not sign the Add-In with the missing private key. The build error message could definitively be improved.

It looks like the import of the private keys to the certificates needed some time to kick in.

Comment: Nope. Private key is imported along with public cert if available. If you imported the cert and General tab doesn't show you that you have a private key, then there is no private key. You must ensure that you are importing the certificate from PFX file, not .cer. `.cer` file contains only public certificate, `.pfx` contains both, public certificate and private key.

Comment: yeah, that's what I meant. Thx for clarification

Comment: The same solution also works for the following error: `error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: Keyset does not exist`